# How to improve performance on this MongoDB aggregation / group query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have MongoDB documents like so:

```
{"purchase_count":3,"view_count":5,"row_uuid":5907170046072864768,"viewer_id":2,"group_id":0,"week_of_year":128961,"epoch_window_start":14516064
00000,"epoch_window_end":1451606973662}
{"purchase_count":1,"view_count":3,"row_uuid":5907175079237664768,"viewer_id":3,"group_id":0,"week_of_year":128961,"epoch_window_start":14516067
00000,"epoch_window_end":1451607267420}
{"purchase_count":1,"view_count":2,"row_uuid":5907175079237664768,"viewer_id":4,"group_id":0,"week_of_year":128961,"epoch_window_start":14516067
00000,"epoch_window_end":1451607161041}
{"purchase_count":7,"view_count":8,"row_uuid":5911055649298464768,"viewer_id":2,"group_id":0,"week_of_year":129026,"epoch_window_start":1451838000000,"epoch_window_end":1451838136249}
{"purchase_count":1,"view_count":1,"row_uuid":5911055649298464768,"viewer_id":3,"group_id":0,"week_of_year":129026,"epoch_window_start":1451838000000,"epoch_window_end":1451838463694}
{"purchase_count":5,"view_count":10,"row_uuid":5911055649298464768,"viewer_id":4,"group_id":0,"week_of_year":129026,"epoch_window_start":1451838000000,"epoch_window_end":1451838331683}
{"purchase_count":1,"view_count":5,"row_uuid":6437705881311264768,"viewer_id":3,"group_id":0,"week_of_year":129077,"epoch_window_start":1483228800000,"epoch_window_end":1483229011517}
```

It is a timeseries-oriented insert case, so the field week_of_year is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing on insert.

I want to aggregate on a specific viewer_id, fetch the sum of view_count and purchase_count on rows at or above a specific week_of_year, and group by week_of_year. This command does what I want:

```
db.viewer_test_window.aggregate(
    [
       { $match: {
         week_of_year: {$gte : 129073 },
         viewer_id: { $eq: 10 }
       } },
       {
         $group : {
            _id : { viewer_id: "$viewer_id", week_of_year: "$week_of_year" },
            purchaseCount: { $sum: "$purchase_count" },
            viewCount: { $sum: "$view_count" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
         }
       }
    ]
 )
```

Is there a way to speed up performance? This is on a single node MongoDB instance with no replication or sharding. The index I have is:

```
db.viewer_test_window.createIndex( { viewerId: 1, week_of_year: -1} )
```